# How to delete div on btn click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove div on button click. I make card view page and i make jquery function for remove a div on remove button click. When i click on remove button the all div is removed. How to fix this error.
I give id="rd" to all remove button. & Give class="mcpd" to all div.

```
$('#rb').click(function(){
    $('.mcpd').remove();
});
```

Comment: you can't duplicate `id` in your DOM. Please give unique `id` to all required elements or better give same class instead. also how is the HTML structure of your page. can you please explain that a bit more.

Comment: You can see example here
https://jsfiddle.net/Usman_Ali/uwvx8hn6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this updated code:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwvx8hn6/4/

I have modified the Remove `span` as follows:

```
<span class="waves-effect waves-light rb">Remove</span>
```

Here we have given `rb` class to all such `span` instead of `id` and on `click` of it we are just removing associated parent `div` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rb').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.mcpd').remove();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work because you want to remove **any div** with the **class "mcpd"**

```js
$("#rd").on("click",function(){
  $("div").remove(".mcpd");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rd" type="button">
Remove
</button>

<div class="mcpd">
mcpd div 1
</div>
<div class="mcpd">
mcpd div 2
</div>
<div class="mcpd">
mcpd div 3
</div>
<div >
No class div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You are trying to remove 1 div, when the user clicks the button, however all the divs are being removed? The reason they are all being removed is because they all have the same class. Give each div a different ID and that should solve your issue.

```
$('#rb').click(function(){
    $('#mcpd1').remove();
});
```

Comment: But in this case i need one function for all divs and remove clicked button div.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather

> I give id="rd" to all remove button. & Give class="mcpd" to all div.

You cannot duplicate ids.

What you have to do is give that button a class and have the id for the corresponding `div` as a `data-` attribute

So your button can be like

```
<a class="rb" data-div="mcpd1">Remove</a>
```

Then you can have your jQuery be like

```
$(".rb").click(function(){
    var div = $(this).attr("data-div");
    $("#" + div).remove();
});
```

If I am mistaken however and you want to delete all the divs on a single button click (provided your ids aren't duplicated) then you can try the following:

```
$("#rb").click(function(){
    $("div.mcpd").remove();
});
```